# Need a regex expression to validate a phone number must contain only the characters +, -, *, ? and 0-9

Tags: javascript, regex

Hope you all are doing good. I am in need of a regex expression where I need to validate the below conditions:

- Phone number must contain only the characters +, -, *, ? and 0-9.
- Only the leading character may be a + (only once it should come, should fail if more than 1 **+** appends to the leading character).
- Only the trailing character may be a *. (only once it should come, should fail if more than 1 * appends to the leading character).
- In between the **+** and *, I can have 20 characters (allowed are 0-9, -, ?).

I have the below expression to validate the leading (**+**) and trailing character (*). It needs to be expanded to validate if more than one same character appends to the leading and trailing character.

```
^[0-9+].*[0-9*]$
```

Comment: "*I have the below expression [...] It needs to be expanded*" where is it?

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Up to 20 characters between optional `+` and `*`... no minimum? Are just `+`, `*` or `?` allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ...

```
^\+?([-?0-9]{0,20})\*?
```

This will match between 0 and 1 of the leading character (+) and trailing character (*).

It'll also check that 0-9, - and ? occur between 0 and 20 times.

So this would match:

- +23-4932-4234?3423*
- 23-4932-4234?3423*
- +23-4932-4234?3423
- 23-4932-42343423
- etc,

Otherwise have a look at the [Regular Expression Library](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=phone).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried the above the expression. It is matching for all the use case, even for failure case ex: +23-4932-4234?ddsfsdf3423*

Comment: Yes, it will capture "+23-4932-4234?", if you require the * at then remove the ? after the * (? = capture zero or one). Alternatively add [^\D] to your capture group to exclude any other non-digits, as follows ... `^\+?([-?0-9]{0,20}[^\D])\*`

Comment: Thanks Ambro. I was able to achieve that using the below modified expression which matches my requirement (considering the trailing character as 0-9 or * or ?). Expression:  ^\+?([-?0-9]{3,23}[^\D])?[-?0-9]+\*?$

Comment: @Karthik, not problem. Glad that it got you on the right path. If you are struggling with Regular Expressions, I find [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) fairly useful. Please just check the tick to mark this as resolved. Thanks.